# Prove by induction that $\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{i} \ge 1+\frac{n}{2}, \forall n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, summation, induction, harmonic-numbers

As the title says I need to prove the following by induction:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{i} \ge 1+\frac{n}{2}, \forall n \in \mathbb N$$

When trying to prove that P(n+1) is true if P(n) is, then I get that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^{n+1}} \frac{1}{i} = (\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{i} ) +(\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{2^n+i} ) \ge 1+\frac{n}{2} + (\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{2^n+i} )$$ using the inductive hypothesis. And for P(n+1) to be true it would be sufficient to prove that  $$1+\frac{n}{2} + (\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{2^n+i} ) \ge 1+\frac{n+1}{2}$$  or rewriting $$\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{2^n+i} \ge \frac{1}{2} $$ and here I'm a bit stuck

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: When I try to prove that P(n+1) is true assuming P(n) is I get to the expression: $\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{2^n +i} \ge \frac{1}{2}$ and here I'm having trouble trying to bound this sum.

Comment: Each term in the sum is at least $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$, and there are $2^n$ of them...

Comment: This might be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Divergence

Comment: Thanks @Joey Zou this is very useful, but I still have to prove it using induction :s

Comment: The inductive step is in there as well--it's just not explicitly stated.

Comment: I edited the post to show where exactly I'm getting stuck

Comment: Note that if $i\leq2^n$ then $\frac1{2^n+i}\geq\frac1{2^{n+1}}$.

Comment: you're right @stewbasic and so: $\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{2^n+i} \ge \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}= \frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}= \frac{1}{2} $ and we're done :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Providing this to make the inductive argument more explicit (some of the details were discussed in the comments): 
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{1}{i}&= \sum_{i=1}^{2^k}\frac{1}{i}+\sum_{i=1}^{2^k}\frac{1}{2^k+i}\tag{rewrite the sum}\\[1em]
&\geq 1+\frac{k}{2}+\sum_{i=1}^{2^k}\frac{1}{2^k+i}\tag{by inductive hypothesis}\\[1em]
&\geq 1+\frac{k}{2}+\sum_{i=1}^{2^k}\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\tag{since $i\leq2^n$}\\[1em]
&= 1+\frac{k}{2}+2^k\left(\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\right)\tag{simplify}\\[1em]
&= 1+\frac{k}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\tag{simplify}\\[1em]
&= 1+\frac{k+1}{2}\tag{simplify}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

See [Inequality of finite harmonic series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196047/inequality-of-finite-harmonic-series)

Also proving $\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{i} \ge 1+\frac{n}{2}, \forall n \in \mathbb N$ clear shows that $1+\frac{n}{2} + (\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{2^n+i} ) \ge 1+\frac{n+1}{2}$ is true since adding $1$ to the LHS and $\frac{1}{2}$ to the RHS holds the inequality.