# How do I prove the inequality $H_{2^m}>1+\frac{m}{2}$?

Tags: inequality, summation

How do I prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{2^m}\frac{1}{k}>1+\frac{m}{2}$?

I have used it in an exercise but I want to know why it is like that.

Comment: Integral test?  Cauchy condensation test?

Comment: The two questions (I am talking about the current one and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851770/prove-by-induction-that-sum-i-12n-frac1i-ge-1-fracn2-forall?noredirect=1&lq=1) are not the same, since in this question we do not have to use induction at all costs. I am voting for reopening.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way: assuming $m\geq 2$,
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{2^m}\frac{1}{k} = 1+\sum_{h=0}^{m-1}\color{red}{\sum_{k=2^h+1}^{2^{h+1}}\frac{1}{k}}>1+\sum_{h=0}^{m-1}\frac{2^h}{2^{h+1}}=1+\frac{m}{2} $$
since every red sum is made by $2^h$ terms, the smallest of them being $\frac{1}{2^{h+1}}$.
This is the key idea of [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).

---

Now something more accurate. Since $\frac{1}{x}$ is decreasing, positive and convex on $\mathbb{R}^+$,
 by the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality) we have:
$$ \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2^m-1}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2^m}>\int_{1}^{2^m}\frac{dx}{x} = m\log(2) $$
hence:
$$ H_{2^m}>\frac{1}{2}+m\log(2) $$
that is a stronger inequality, since $\log(2)\approx\frac{61}{88}>\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: One minor thing: The inequality is $\geq$ because of $m=1$ case.

Comment: @i707107: oh, right. Thanks, answer fixed.

Comment: What is wrong about this answer to deserve a downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote. I actually upvoted after your edit.